# How to read binary contents of free disk space in CentOS

Tags: centos7, disk-image, dd

Is there a way I can use dd or another tool to view the binary contents of free disk space in CentOS?  In case it matters, it's a Linux logical volume with XFS format, holding data only (not a common system volume such as / or /var).

Some process had filled one of the volumes with a single output file, when the file was expected to be small.  To unblock the host's services, the file was deleted and a reboot was needed.  I want to dump a few megabytes from a few places on the now-freed disk space, so I can examine the binary data and see if there was some sort of infinite looping error text/data in hopes of finding and addressing the root cause.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest is probably indeed with `dd`.

```
dd if=/dev/VG_NAME/LV_NAME of=/tmp/partition.data skip=500M bs=1M count=5
```

will `skip` the first 500 Megabytes of raw data from the block device and then copy out `count=5` * 1 Megabyte of raw data to the filename specified with `of`.

Read and repeat with different offsets.

Comment: Thanks, but I had only wanted to read some chunks of free partition space, while this proposal reads volume data indiscriminately based on the offset.  Is there a way to only select data from unused partition space?